# A variation of the Assignment Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

In the following Wikipedia article about the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in the [Example section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Example), it says:

> > Similar tricks can be played in order to allow more tasks than agents, tasks to which multiple agents must be assigned (for instance, a group of more customers than will fit in one taxi), or maximizing profit rather than minimizing cost.

I have a problem where an agent can do several tasks and a task can be assigned to multiple agents. The only two contraints are:

1. to have everyone working and all tasks are assigned
2. no length 3 path, meaning if an agent is working on several tasks, non of these tasks will be assigned to different agents.

Maybe a variantion of [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) can apply here, but I can not find how would that be.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me, or guide me to where I can find the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment problem is simply a special case of a [transportation problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_problem) and in turn a very very special of a simple LPP. Therefore, if there is any deviation from the usual structure, we should be good with reverting to the back-end.